# <mx:HTML/> link trouble

Tags: html, apache-flex, air

I create a AD area as a  in my Fx app.

http://www.triafx.com/ReklamKampanyasi/reklam.html

But link not work when it was clicked.

What is my wrong?

Comment: Please post the code you're using, maybe that would help us get to the bottom of it.

Comment: the code is available on the link he gave, but it is extremely short so no harm in posting it here

Comment: I was referring to the mxml code. Also, the question needs to be rephrased. What link? All I see is a red rectangle that when clicked opens another web page.

Answer (score 0):

the link works for me. Do you have some aggressive popup blocker?

edit: (firefox 3.0.10)